# Ember.js - Getting App instance in module

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have to port a non-cli project to the cli. I have a route that is:

```
App.thisRoute = App.previouslyDefinedRoute.extend({...})
```

With the CLI, I've tried this:

```
// routes/thisRoute.js
import App from 'app';

export default App.previouslyDefinedRoute.extend({...})
```

That gives me this Ember Inspector Error:

> Ember Inspector has errored.
>
> ...
>
> Error message: Could not find module `app` imported from `app/routes/thisRoute`

I've also tried:

```
// routes/thisRoute.js
import App from 'routes/previouslyDefinedRoute.js';

export default App.previouslyDefinedRoute.extend({...})
```

Both dont work.

**How do I get my app instance?**

Comment: There is no app instance, ember-cli uses ES6 modules, meaning each bit is isolated from the rest and needs to import what it needs and export what needs to be available for other files.

What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have a route that extends another route's basic functions. So instead of `App.route = Ember.Route.extend` it'd be `App.route = PreviousRoute.extend`

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to port an old app to the CLI with as few changes as possible. I'll refactor it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no app instance in ember-cli, it uses ES6 modules instead, in order to extend a route you will have to import it first.

`import PreviousRoute from 'yourProjectName/routes/previouslyDefinedRoute';`

Note that the file extension is not needed.

And then you can just `export default PreviousRoute.extend({});`.

Your files must always export either a default or a named function in order to be used by other files.

Comment: You can use a relative path, but I find absolute paths for imports to be easier to read.